# Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest can't get orig countryid

Tags: shipping-methods

I want to use `DestCountryId` and `OrigCountryId` to calculation shipping price in my customer shipping method.

So I use `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest`.  `$request->getDestCountryId()`  I can get country code, but `$request->getOrigCountryId()` is empty.

> what should I do for get `OrigCuntryId`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `origCountryId` is never populated.
The rate request object is populated in `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address::requestShippingRates`. There is no trace of `orig` in there.
Actually I looked for `getOrigCountryId` everywhere. It only appears in the method hinting in the class RateRequest.
Also looked for `orig_coutry_id`. It only appears in test classes.
If you want to get the data configured in `Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping settings -> Origin` you can do it via `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::getValue()`.
So just like reading any other value from config.

Make your class have a dependency called `scopeConfig`.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
 */
private $scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    ...
}
```

then you can get the country like this:

```
$originCountryId = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('shipping/origin/country_id', 'website');
$originCity = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('shipping/origin/city', 'website');
....
```